# Explanation of this docker file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to understand this docker [file](https://github.com/wurstmeister/docker-base/blob/master/Dockerfile)

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
MAINTAINER Wurstmeister 
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y unzip openjdk-7-jre-headless wget supervisor docker.io openssh-server
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
RUN echo 'root:wurstmeister' | chpasswd
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin without-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

EXPOSE 22
```

I understood most of the lines but I don't understand what these below lines means?

```
apt-get install -y unzip openjdk-7-jre-headless wget supervisor docker.io openssh-server
echo 'root:wurstmeister' | chpasswd
sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin without-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Can anyone help me understand? I am not sure what is the purpose of `wget supervisor docker.io openssh-server` in that line. Also what does echo mean there? And then also last sed line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
apt-get install -y unzip openjdk-7-jre-headless wget supervisor docker.io openssh-server
```

Installs a bunch of packages using the ubuntu package manager (the base image is Ubuntu Trusty 14.04).

The `-y` option is used to prevent apt from asking user confirmation about installing the packages and their dependencies: the installation just proceeds without need for any input. This is needed to avoid hanging the process of building the docker image. Packages installed:

- openssh-server: so that the container can act as an ssh server and process requests from ssh clients
- wget, unzip: utilities
- java: eventually this container is used to allow users to access it via ssh, maybe those users need java
- supervisor, docker.io: I don't see a direct usage of it in the Dockerfile itself

then

```
echo 'root:wurstmeister' | chpasswd
```

Changes password of user root to `wurstmeister`

```
sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin without-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Replaces the text `PermitRootLogin without-password` with `PermitRootLogin yes` in file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to allow root user to login with password or without (e.g., with public key).

An important general note: [If you run SSHD in your Docker containers, you're doing it wrong!](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/)

Comment: You meant without right? `allow root user to login with password`

Comment: @david, oops, I'll fix it. But that change means allowing root to login not only without-password :).

Answer (score 2):

`wget supervisor docker.io openssh-server` are parameters to the `apt-get` call. Those are the names of the packages to be installed.

`echo` is used in combination with `|` to send the new password to the `chpasswd` command.

`sed` is used to update some text in a configuration file (here to allow passwordless login). The `s/text/newText/` part does text substitution.